# Importing 40k PDF as attchments

Tags: data-loader, attachment, bulk-api, data-import

I have 40k PDF's in windows shared drive. Each pdf should be attached to parent account. The name of each pdf is an external ID in salesforce. 
e.g AA123.pdf corresponds to AccountRecordId '0015C00000OaTWhQAN' AA456 corresponds to AccountRecordId '0015C00000OaRWhAVN'

My question is when i prepare my csv to be uploaded via Dataloader, how can i get the path of each pdf without having to type the path ?

e.g path of AA123.pdf is S:\IT\Database\Attachments\Extracts\AA123.pdf

Is there any utility program or do i have to write a script that will go through each pdf in the folder, extract the absolute path and create a csv. ?

Comment: does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload Files there is "PathOnClient" field I think, you specify it and DataLoader will use it as a location for a file. You upload those files as ContentVersion and then to link them with the account you separately upload ContentDocumentLink records. Keep in mind that you can upload ~100k Files a day
[image]
[image]

P.S. after you upload files result "success" file should contain Ids and Names for your files, so there should be no problem for generating upload file for ContentDocumentLink

Comment: I think I did not pose my original question correctly.  The .csv that i need to upload should have the path of each of the attachments. I would like to automate the creation of csv file. i.e one column will have the name if the file and other will have the path of the file.

Comment: Do you have your files on your computer that you want to upload?

Comment: yes I have the files on my computer that i want to upload

Comment: So you specify pass to them in your CSV file and this path info into PathOnClient

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you know to upload SObjects with DataLoader? ContentVersion is an SObject and I said you how to populate the fields, so what is the problem?

Comment: I wrote Power Shell Script to do what i needed.  Good for now. Thank you !